# SQLAlchemy 2.0 NotImplementedError: engine.execute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am getting a `NotImplementedError: This method is not implemented for SQLAlchemy 2.0.`, when trying to delete a table using the `delete` method in SQLAlchemy v1.4.15.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, MetaData, String, Table, create_engine, delete

engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:", echo=True, future=True)
metadata = MetaData()

user = Table(
    "users", metadata, Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True), Column("name", String)
)

metadata.create_all(engine)

engine.execute(user.delete())  # leading to Traceback
# NotImplementedError: This method is not implemented for SQLAlchemy 2.0.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[engine.execute](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=engine%20execute#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.execute) is deprecated in SQLAlchemy 1.4, and will be removed in SQLAlchemy 2.0.  You need to call a connection's [execute](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute) method instead:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, MetaData, String, Table, create_engine, delete

# Setting future=True enforces 2.0 behaviour in 1.4.x and disables
# legacy features. 
engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:", echo=True, future=True)
metadata = MetaData()

user = Table(
    "users", metadata, Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True), Column("name", String)
)

metadata.create_all(engine)

stmt = delete(user)
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(stmt)
```

Comment: `with engine.begin() as conn:` works, too. The difference between `with engine.connect()` and `with engine.begin()` is that absent an explicit `.commit()` the former will automatically roll back while the latter will automatically commit.